# d3 arc transition anticlockwise not clockwise

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am looking at having two animated donut graphs and need to animate them a certain way.

If you look at the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5uc1xfxm/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    .animated-ring {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  //margin-top: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
  </style>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
var tau = 2 * Math.PI; // http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto

// An arc function with all values bound except the endAngle. So, to compute an
// SVG path string for a given angle, we pass an object with an endAngle
// property to the `arc` function, and it will return the corresponding string.
var arc1 = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(45)
  .outerRadius(90)
  .startAngle(0.75 * tau);

var arc2 = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(45)
  .outerRadius(90)
  .startAngle(0.25 * tau);

// Get the SVG container, and apply a transform such that the origin is the
// center of the canvas. This way, we don’t need to position arcs individually.
var svg1 = d3.select("#anim1"),
  width = +svg1.attr("width"),
  height = +svg1.attr("height"),
  g = svg1.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var svg2 = d3.select("#anim2"),
  width = +svg2.attr("width"),
  height = +svg2.attr("height"),
  h = svg2.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

// Add the background arc, from 0 to 100% (tau).
var background1 = g.append("path")
  .datum({
    endAngle: tau
  })
  .style("fill", "transparent")
  .attr("d", arc1);

var background2 = h.append("path")
  .datum({
    endAngle: tau
  })
  .style("fill", "transparent")
  .attr("d", arc2);

// Add the foreground arc in orange, currently showing 12.7%.
var foreground1 = g.append("path")
  .datum({
    endAngle: 0.75 * tau
  })
  .style("fill", "#EF4939")
  .attr("d", arc1);

var foreground2 = h.append("path")
  .datum({
    endAngle: 0.25 * tau
  })
  .style("fill", "blue")
  .attr("d", arc2);

// Every so often, start a transition to a new random angle. The attrTween
// definition is encapsulated in a separate function (a closure) below.
d3.timer(function() {
  foreground1.transition()
    .duration(75)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween(0 * tau));
  foreground2.transition()
    .duration(75)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween2(0.5 * tau));
});

// Returns a tween for a transition’s "d" attribute, transitioning any selected
// arcs from their current angle to the specified new angle.
function arcTween(newAngle) {

  // The function passed to attrTween is invoked for each selected element when
  // the transition starts, and for each element returns the interpolator to use
  // over the course of transition. This function is thus responsible for
  // determining the starting angle of the transition (which is pulled from the
  // element’s bound datum, d.endAngle), and the ending angle (simply the
  // newAngle argument to the enclosing function).
  return function(d) {

    // To interpolate between the two angles, we use the default d3.interpolate.
    // (Internally, this maps to d3.interpolateNumber, since both of the
    // arguments to d3.interpolate are numbers.) The returned function takes a
    // single argument t and returns a number between the starting angle and the
    // ending angle. When t = 0, it returns d.endAngle; when t = 1, it returns
    // newAngle; and for 0 < t < 1 it returns an angle in-between.
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);

    // The return value of the attrTween is also a function: the function that
    // we want to run for each tick of the transition. Because we used
    // attrTween("d"), the return value of this last function will be set to the
    // "d" attribute at every tick. (It’s also possible to use transition.tween
    // to run arbitrary code for every tick, say if you want to set multiple
    // attributes from a single function.) The argument t ranges from 0, at the
    // start of the transition, to 1, at the end.
    return function(t) {

      // Calculate the current arc angle based on the transition time, t. Since
      // the t for the transition and the t for the interpolate both range from
      // 0 to 1, we can pass t directly to the interpolator.
      //
      // Note that the interpolated angle is written into the element’s bound
      // data object! This is important: it means that if the transition were
      // interrupted, the data bound to the element would still be consistent
      // with its appearance. Whenever we start a new arc transition, the
      // correct starting angle can be inferred from the data.
      d.endAngle = interpolate(t);

      // Lastly, compute the arc path given the updated data! In effect, this
      // transition uses data-space interpolation: the data is interpolated
      // (that is, the end angle) rather than the path string itself.
      // Interpolating the angles in polar coordinates, rather than the raw path
      // string, produces valid intermediate arcs during the transition.
      return arc1(d);
    };
  };
}

// Returns a tween for a transition’s "d" attribute, transitioning any selected
// arcs from their current angle to the specified new angle.
function arcTween2(newAngle) {
  return function(d) {
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);
    return function(t) {
            d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
      return arc2(d);
    };
  };
}
}//]]> 

</script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="animated-ring">
  <svg width="200" height="200" id="anim1"></svg>
  <svg width="200" height="200" id="anim2"></svg>
</div>

  <script>
  // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
  if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
    window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
      height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
      slug: "5uc1xfxm"
    }], "*")
  }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

You will see the two animations. The orange graph is working as required but the blue graph isn't.

The start and end positions are correct but instead of it moving clockwise and filling only a quarter of the circle. I need it to move anti-clockwise and fill three quarters of the circle.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understand the problem,

Instead of having the arc transition from 0.25 tau to 0.5 tau, try -0.5 tau:

```
.attrTween("d", arcTween2(-0.5 * tau));
```

This will move the arc backwards and cause it to fill 3/4 of the complete donut. This fits the pattern from the first donut which behaves properly, where the ultimate end angle is less than the start angle.

Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f0yfLqh6/)

And a snippet using your code for good measure (I've changed the order of the donuts so you don't need to quickly scroll):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    .animated-ring {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  //margin-top: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
  </style>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
var tau = 2 * Math.PI; // http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto

// An arc function with all values bound except the endAngle. So, to compute an
// SVG path string for a given angle, we pass an object with an endAngle
// property to the `arc` function, and it will return the corresponding string.
var arc1 = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(45)
  .outerRadius(90)
  .startAngle(0.75 * tau);

var arc2 = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(45)
  .outerRadius(90)
  .startAngle(0.25 * tau);

// Get the SVG container, and apply a transform such that the origin is the
// center of the canvas. This way, we don’t need to position arcs individually.
var svg1 = d3.select("#anim1"),
  width = +svg1.attr("width"),
  height = +svg1.attr("height"),
  g = svg1.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var svg2 = d3.select("#anim2"),
  width = +svg2.attr("width"),
  height = +svg2.attr("height"),
  h = svg2.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

// Add the background arc, from 0 to 100% (tau).
var background1 = g.append("path")
  .datum({
    endAngle: tau
  })
  .style("fill", "transparent")
  .attr("d", arc1);

var background2 = h.append("path")
  .datum({
    endAngle: tau
  })
  .style("fill", "transparent")
  .attr("d", arc2);

// Add the foreground arc in orange, currently showing 12.7%.
var foreground1 = g.append("path")
  .datum({
    endAngle: 0.75 * tau
  })
  .style("fill", "#EF4939")
  .attr("d", arc1);

var foreground2 = h.append("path")
  .datum({
    endAngle: 0.25 * tau
  })
  .style("fill", "blue")
  .attr("d", arc2);

// Every so often, start a transition to a new random angle. The attrTween
// definition is encapsulated in a separate function (a closure) below.
d3.timer(function() {
  foreground1.transition()
    .duration(75)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween(0 * tau));
  foreground2.transition()
    .duration(75)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween2(-0.5 * tau));
});

// Returns a tween for a transition’s "d" attribute, transitioning any selected
// arcs from their current angle to the specified new angle.
function arcTween(newAngle) {

  // The function passed to attrTween is invoked for each selected element when
  // the transition starts, and for each element returns the interpolator to use
  // over the course of transition. This function is thus responsible for
  // determining the starting angle of the transition (which is pulled from the
  // element’s bound datum, d.endAngle), and the ending angle (simply the
  // newAngle argument to the enclosing function).
  return function(d) {

    // To interpolate between the two angles, we use the default d3.interpolate.
    // (Internally, this maps to d3.interpolateNumber, since both of the
    // arguments to d3.interpolate are numbers.) The returned function takes a
    // single argument t and returns a number between the starting angle and the
    // ending angle. When t = 0, it returns d.endAngle; when t = 1, it returns
    // newAngle; and for 0 < t < 1 it returns an angle in-between.
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);

    // The return value of the attrTween is also a function: the function that
    // we want to run for each tick of the transition. Because we used
    // attrTween("d"), the return value of this last function will be set to the
    // "d" attribute at every tick. (It’s also possible to use transition.tween
    // to run arbitrary code for every tick, say if you want to set multiple
    // attributes from a single function.) The argument t ranges from 0, at the
    // start of the transition, to 1, at the end.
    return function(t) {

      // Calculate the current arc angle based on the transition time, t. Since
      // the t for the transition and the t for the interpolate both range from
      // 0 to 1, we can pass t directly to the interpolator.
      //
      // Note that the interpolated angle is written into the element’s bound
      // data object! This is important: it means that if the transition were
      // interrupted, the data bound to the element would still be consistent
      // with its appearance. Whenever we start a new arc transition, the
      // correct starting angle can be inferred from the data.
      d.endAngle = interpolate(t);

      // Lastly, compute the arc path given the updated data! In effect, this
      // transition uses data-space interpolation: the data is interpolated
      // (that is, the end angle) rather than the path string itself.
      // Interpolating the angles in polar coordinates, rather than the raw path
      // string, produces valid intermediate arcs during the transition.
      return arc1(d);
    };
  };
}

// Returns a tween for a transition’s "d" attribute, transitioning any selected
// arcs from their current angle to the specified new angle.
function arcTween2(newAngle) {
  return function(d) {
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);
    return function(t) {
            d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
      return arc2(d);
    };
  };
}
}//]]> 

</script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="animated-ring">
  <svg width="200" height="200" id="anim2"></svg>
  <svg width="200" height="200" id="anim1"></svg>

</div>

  <script>
  // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
  if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
    window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
      height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
      slug: "5uc1xfxm"
    }], "*")
  }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what you get for trying to code with a fever and a sick child you lose all obvious logic. Thanks for helping out my brain